# HTTP2 bidirectional communication between two servers

Tags: http, websocket, tcp, http2

I have been recently giving a lot of thought to implementing a solution where I would have two servers (**Server A** which **belongs to me**, and **server B** which would be an **external integrator**) that would be able to exchange messages over the same established TCP connection. I read quite broad discussions and seems like I feel a bit stuck with the ideal case scenario and technology selection.

I considered:

**HTTP/2** - seems like it supports bidirectional communication but as far I understood it is not fully symmetric, meaning there is no way to implement a scenario where I could initiate the connection from server B to A, server A would respond with 1 to many messages and on the server B I could react to them and respond to server B if the specific message requires it

**WebSockets** - seem like the natural choice, multiplexing and streaming data back and forth seems to match my use case, but overall I am a bit skeptical if it would be a good idea to use third-party integrators to connect to such server via WebSocket

I would be grateful for any feedback regarding my assumptions. Have I got the initial against/after right?

Comment: The requirement is pretty unspecific - basically this is just exchange data. No idea about the necessary flows (can anybody initiate data transfer?), size of data, bandwidth requirement, reliability requirements, security requirements, latency requirements .... . One cannot argue about what protocols might be a good or bad choice without having the actual requirements these protocols should match.